# What does "noch" mean in "Ich wünsche Ihnen noch einen schönen Abend"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

At the end of the news program Tagesschau the host always says "Ich wünsche Ihnen noch einen schönen Abend". Today a German typed that to me as well at the end of a conversation. I understand the sentence, but what's the functionality of "noch" here exactly? Is it here to signify a kind of meaning of "in addition", "before we go", "one last thing"?

Comment: Since you've already spent part of the evening with the speaker, it would be impolite to presume that this was a source of pleasure for you. Therefore the polite thing to do is to wish you well for the *rest* of the evening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To me, *noch* refers to the fact that the evening has already begun. An approximate equivalent in English would be:

> Enjoy the **rest of** your evening.

You can also say on Sunday after shopping at the baker's:

> Ich wünsche Ihnen noch einen schönen Sonntag.

But you wouldn't say it on Saturday – then you'd need to omit the *noch*.

================

Re. comments: Sorry for being ambiguous above. I meant that on Saturday, you wouldn’t wish ***noch*** einen schönen **Sonntag**. You can obviously say *noch einen schönen **Samstag***. Or, if there is reason to explicitly refer to the next day (e.g. because you have been told that some special activities will be taking place): *einen schönen/erträglichen/etc. Sonntag (dann)* (without *noch*, and with an optional *dann* that emphasises that you are referring back to your previous discussion about the next day’s activities).

Comment: Why wouldn't one use it in *Wünsche Ihnen noch einen schönen Samstag*? The wish addresses the remainder, and the day had already begun.

Comment: Upvoted because I think it describes the crucial point. Nonetheless, I disagree with the bit about Saturday. You probably want to point out the vendor will not have a nice Saturday because they have to work. Still, the day (or at least parts thereof) could be nice anyway, and your reasoning should be made more explicit. Otherwise, language learners might quickly misinterpret this as a weird language rule that you cannot use the word *noch* on Saturday or such nonsense.

Comment: @dakab & @ O. R. Mapper, I think, you misinterpreted the last sentence: It states that you do not use the sentence `Ich wünsche Ihnen noch einen schönen Sonntag.` in Saturday, because it's not Sunday. So, on Saturday, you have to omit the word *noch*. But if you want to wish someone a pleasant Saturday (on Saturday of course), you certainly use `Ich wünsche Ihnen noch einen schönen Samstag.`. You only use *noch* on the same day, time of day, and so on.

Comment: @biolauri: I thought of that, but dismissed it, because it wouldn’t make any sense at all to wish so. a pleasant Sunday on some day other than that particular Sunday. You probably say *Schönes Wochenende* on Saturday to include Sunday. If that last sentence was intended as you think we may have misinterpreted, the answer should be clarified insofar.

Comment: @biolauri: Whose? What example exactly?

Comment: @dakab: I do wish a pleasant Sunday on Saturday, especially in the evening. But maybe the example of @Endre Both is a bit weird. Your sentence `Ich wünsche (noch) ein schönes Wochenende` ist better: I would use it with *noch* on Saturday and Sunday, bot not on Thursday or Friday (and I use it on all four days of the week. So maybe, that's a bit better? And also sorry for commenting to early, just hit the wrong button. So I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: I agree that *Wochenende* makes for a better example to illustrate the meaning of *noch*, and also that usually, you do not wish a nice next day, so my example was a bit contrived – I have clarified as much above.

Comment: German is not my mother tongue but I think this answer is  not complete. For example, when *Viel Spaß noch* is said, how could one interpret it with *rest of* ?

Comment: @AdInfinitum: It implicitly refers to the current activity/event/stay.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper then, it is more "as of now" instead of "rest of something"?

Comment: @AdInfinitum: The focus is on the remainder of the current activity/event/stay, after the moment of making the statement.

Answer (score 5):

This is one of those German particles that are tricky to translate to English...

I would probably go with

```
I wish you a continued pleasant evening (after I stopped talking to you).
```

As @EndreBoth mentions in his answer,  this implies, that said evening has already started. And as you mentioned, it also has a bit of "goodbye" in the background.

In French, I'd translate it to "Bon soirée!" instead of "Bon soir.", if this is any help.

Comment: +1. The *noch* makes the sentence a goodbye message.

Comment: @Janka: But "Ich wünsche Ihnen einen schönen Abend." is equally suitable as a goodbye message.

Comment: I think, the word *noch* can strengthen the goodbye of the message, albeit it is already in the sentence without the *noch*.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: *Ich wünsche Ihnen einen schönen Abend.* could also be said as a welcome message.

Answer (score 0):

In this case "noch" is used in the sense of "noch mehr".

Noch mehr schöne Zeit an diesem Abend in this case.

Comment: Noch mehr als was?